# Suspected bug in USARSim/ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
After several attempts I have been able to generate a bag file containing logged

transform and laser scan data. when I type

***root@ubuntu:~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox# rosbag info mylaserdata.bag***

path:        mylaserdata.bag

version:     2.0

duration:    7:28s (448s)

start:       Oct 31 2013 21:20:39.34 (1383234639.34)

end:         Oct 31 2013 21:28:07.46 (1383235087.46)

size:        3.7 MB

messages:    24650

compression: none [5/5 chunks]

***types:       tf/tfMessage [94810edda583a504dfda3829e70d7eec]***

***topics:      /tf   24650 msgs    : tf/tfMessage (2 connections)***

**But a standard bag from willow garage contains**

types:        sensor_msgs/LaserScan [90c7ef2dc6895d81024acba2ac42f369]
tf/tfMessage          [94810edda583a504dfda3829e70d7eec]

topics:       /base_scan    924 msgs    : sensor_msgs/LaserScan

```
          /tf          2769 msgs    : tf/tfMessage
```

**I started gmapping by**

rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=lms200 _odom_frame:=odom

**so there is no information regarding /lms200**.

**rxgraph output gives no information of the error**
[image: image description]

***but rviz information does not match with auto generated transform tree. There is no messeges in /lms200 and we have to manually add /lms200 through rviz window***
[image: image description]

**Again  rostopic echo /lms200 to see if there are any published messages
Then nothing appears.**

**PLZ help**.

*** I know this USARSim/Ros is used in robo cup as well but no one mentioned about the error.***

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/96451/suspected-bug-in-usarsim/ros/) by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2013-10-31

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2013-10-31**:
How did you record that bag file? Was "/lms200" topic available during recording?

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2013-10-31**:
ZdenekM, rosbag record -O mylaserdata.bag /lms200 /tf. But no sensor message in the information. So ultimately /lms200 can't capture the messege.

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2013-10-31**:
Did you check if the laser topic was available during recording? Can you try to run your simulation and then "rostopic list" to see what topics are available?

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2013-10-31**:
I haven't check that one, but rxgraph out put gives /lms200. I will check and tell. Have you figured out the problem.

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2013-10-31**:
You can also try "rostopic echo /lms200" to see if there are any published messages...

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2013-10-31**:
Have you received LaserScan messeges correctly using USARSim/ROS

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2013-10-31**:
I'm not using USARSim.

**Comment by [kr1zz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4727/kr1zz/) on 2013-11-03**:
The bug is that the tf tree instantiated by USARSimRos does not contain the /lms200 node, although expected.

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2013-11-04**:
TF has nothing to do with publishing messages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. Use UDK-2013-07 and USARSim-current ($ git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/usarsim/code usarsim-code 
   (Under proxy, please try "$ git clone http://git.code.sf.net/p/usarsim/code usarsim-code"))

---

Originally posted by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) with karma: 229 on 2013-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0